# Topic model for each row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, gensim

I have a *subset* of a dataframe that looks like (note, the new_tags are *not* exhaustively illustrated here):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PageNumber': [175, 162, 576], 'new_tags': [['flower architecture people'], ['hair red bobbles'], ['sweets chocolate shop']})

<OUT>
PageNumber   new_tags
   175       flower architecture people...
   162       hair red bobbles...
   576       sweets chocolate shop...
```

**I am hoping to iterate through each row (also termed a document) and conduct a topic model then extract the top 20 words from each topic into a csv. I am using Gensim.**

I have the code that works for conducting the topic model, but I am unsure how to do this by row. The issue I think I am having is that when converting the df into a dictionary it doesn't allow me to subset it for the loop.

***Here is my progress at the moment:***

***First, I want to tokenize and lemmatize the tags.***

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md', disable=['parser', 'ner'])

def lemmatization(texts,allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ']): 
       output = []
       for sent in texts:
             doc = nlp(sent) 
             output.append([token.lemma_ for token in doc if token.pos_ in allowed_postags ])
       return output

#convert column to list
text_list=df['new_tags'].tolist()

#lemmatisation and tokenisation
tokenized_tags = lemmatization(text_list)
```

***Next, I define a function to conduct a topic model and then write that to the csv.***

```
i = 1
def topic_model(tokenized_tags):
    ''' this function is used to conduct topic modelling for each grid/document '''
    for row in tokenized_tags:
    #convert tokenized lists into dictionary
        dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(row)
        #create document term matrix
        doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(tag) for tag in row]
        #initialise topic model from gensim
        LDA = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel
        #build and train topic model
        lda_model = LDA(corpus=doc_term_matrix, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=40, random_state=100, chunksize=400, passes=50,iterations=100)
        #write top 20 words from each document as csv
        top_words_per_topic = []
        for t in range(lda_model.num_topics):
            top_words_per_topic.extend([(t, ) + x for x in lda_model.show_topic(t, topn = 20)])
        #return csv - write first row then append subsequent rows
    return pd.DataFrame(top_words_per_topic, columns=['Topic', 'Word', 'P']).to_csv("top_words.csv", mode='a', index = False, header=False)
    i+=1
topic_model(tokenized_tags)
```

As a side note, is there a way to work out the optimal parameters e.g. coherence value for each document after running the topic model and somehow adjust the model to take in the best value?

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

---

**UPDATED CODE:**
I've updated the function so I'm passing the tokenized version of the df and wanting to apply a topic model to each row and append that onto the df as a new column. How will I be able to do this?

```
tokens = central_edi_posts_grouped['new_tags'].astype(str).apply(nltk.word_tokenize)

def topic_model(central_edi_posts_grouped):
    ''' this function is used to conduct topic modelling for each grid/document '''
    #convert tokenized lists into dictionary
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tokens)
    #create document term matrix
    doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(tag) for tag in tokens]
    #initialise topic model from gensim
    LDA = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel
    #build and train topic model
    lda_model = LDA(corpus=doc_term_matrix, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=8, random_state=100,
                chunksize=400, passes=50,iterations=100)
    #let's check out the coheence number 
    from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel
    coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=tokens, dictionary=dictionary , coherence='c_v')
    coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()

    #write top 20 words from each document as csv
    top_words_per_topic = []
    for t in range(lda_model.num_topics):
        top_words_per_topic.extend([(t, ) + x for x in lda_model.show_topic(t, topn = 20)])
    #return csv - write first row then append subsequent rows
    pd.DataFrame(top_words_per_topic, coherence_lda, columns=['Topic', 'Word', 'P', 'Coherence_value']).to_csv("top_words_loop_test.csv", mode='a', index = False, header=False)
    return coherence_lda


df['new_col'] = df['new_tags'].apply(lambda tokens: topic_model((tokens)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply()` function in Pandas to conduct row iterations.

```
df['new_col'] = df['new_tags'].apply(lambda text_list: topic_model(lemmatization(text_list)))
```

You may have to modify your `topic_model()` function a bit, so that it returns just the values you need, but not a pd.DataFrame.

Comment: Will try this, thanks. I just wondered would that work as I thought Gensim would need a dictionary to conduct the topic model? Or is it that I can loop through each row in the `df['new_col']` and convert that into a dictionary? Many thanks.

Comment: I tried the above code but it doesn't work. I wondered whether you could explain your code?

Comment: `apply()` is simply an operation row-by-row. eg. `df['column'].apply(lambda x: x+1)` will add one to each data in `df['column']`. So in your case, `.apply(lambda text_list: topic_model(lemmatization(text_list)))` will conduct ` topic_model(lemmatization(text_list))` to each row of item in df['new_tags'], and return them to a new column named `'new_col'`.

Comment: Thank for the explanation. I've updated the code in the question so I'm removing lemmatization. I wondered how I may be able to do this using the new function. I tried using your code but adapted but never worked. Thanks!